# Objects should not be both modified and additional

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, core-data, cloudkit

Part of a project I'm working in involves managing storages for products.
A `Storage` object contains `StorageShelf` objects, which define the amount of shelves. A StorageShelf, in turn, contains some other objects such as `StorageLocation` objects that determine the amount of products that can fit on a shelf. All These objects exist in CoreData. I also store `Storages` and `StorageShelfs` in a CloudKit database for synchronization purposes.

If I am running my app on two iPads, and add a storage with some shelves on one of the devices, it receives the notifications on the other and starts processing the updates it received.

I have a CloudOperationQueue in my app that has a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 1, in order to make sure only one update is made at the same time (This is because all objects of my app, also those out of the scope of this question are highly interdependent).

Inconsitently, this results in the following `SIGABRT` error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Objects should not be both modified and additional'
```

Specifically, this error occurs when I save the context after making modifications to one of the shelf objects I received. There is no consistency in which shelf.

**Question**

What does this error mean, and how can one debug it?

Answer (score 2):

I recently got this error, also inconsistently. The issue was connected to adding an object and then saving the CoreData context on a background thread (part of a drag and drop update), while also trying to update a view showing a list of the objects on the main thread.

The fix is to cause things to happen synchronously, for me the easy fix was moving the save operation to the main thread, like (in Swift):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // save your context
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error recently, and also inconsistently. I had several core data objects with a 1:many relation and randomly when I would add an object to that relation and save context I would receive this exception.

For me the problem turned out to be I was using the `NSPersistentContainer.viewcontext`

1. in a background thread and
2. to write to core data

whehn according to these docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer viewcontext should be read only for the main queue. Switching to `NSpersistentContainer.newBackgroundContext` instead fixed the issue.